# Colorbox not showing up in IE

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Hy,

i'm trying to use colorbox and it works great so far (in Chrome & Firefox), but just doesn't work in Internet Explorer (i have Version 9 [on Win7 64bit) and tried setting any version in the Developer Tools window, but none works).

I have tried a LOT of the suggestions that i found (doctype change/fix, console.__ not defined, ...) nothing works.

I get no unusual log output, i have tried my selector which i use to apply colorbox() via the developer tools console and it gets the right elements.
The code also gets called (verified via log outputs).

1 thing i noticed which i found a little strange was that in Chrome colorbox generates this DOM entry at the end of the page:

```
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 42px; padding-right: 42px; ">
```

whereas IE gets this:

```
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="display: none;" >
```

but i couldn't find out why.

I have tried disabling any other css that i have, without any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what it was... My page should be HTML5 and i use Modernizr (javascript library which checks/fixes some HTML5 related stuff) i basically only use it to check via a media-query if the user has a small device (tablet/phone) or desktop.

The problem was somehow related to media-queries. Just embedding the modernizr library did no harm (without any calls to it). But as soon as i executed a media query via modernizr, colorbox no longer worked!

To test it i removed all calls to the modernizr library & the library --> Colorbox worked like a charm!

I now downloaded a slightly newer version of modernizr (i had 2.5.__ and updated to 2.6.1) and now Colorbox works even when using Modernizr!

This problem only affected Internet Explorer, so i am guessing it is/was a bug in the old Modernizr version which only occured in IE.

This cost me hours... so i guess my lesson learned is: don't ever use any JS libraries which you don't really need.

Comment: asked **and** answered nnn seconds ago. *Wow*.

Comment: you can answer questions yourself already when you ask them (it's a feature of StackOverflow) It is because they know that when you write up (and therefore research) your question it happens quite often actually, that you will find a solution yourself and they still want to encourage you to share that knowledge because it may help others. Its similar to the idea of rubber-ducking (+ sharing what you found out).

Comment: they even have a blog entry on this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/